# Import error when importing MsgPackSerializer

Tags: python, python-3.x, autobahn, serialization

I am trying to import the MsgPackSerializer from autobahn library. But I am getting the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name MsgPackSerializer
```

I have tried this solution but did not work - https://github.com/Crypto-Expert/stratum-mining/issues/211#issuecomment-33867305

Using Miniconda 3.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, it seems that I had to do `pip install u-msgpack-python`.

Answer (score 0):

For python 3 you need `pip install msgpack`. Tested in python 3.7 Autobahn 20.3.1 .
Don't forget to uninstall `u-msgpack-python` if you had it installed.